# vbscript-terminating process instance

Tags: process, vbscript

I'm writing a script that runs an external program, and after a while terminates it, the relevant code section looks like this:

```
Set objshell=createObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.run ""app.exe""
objShell.run ""app.exe""
WScript.Sleep(5000)

strWmiq = "select * from Win32_Process where name='app.exe'" 
Set objQResult = objWmi.Execquery(strWmiq)
    For Each objProcess In objQResult 
        intRet = objProcess.Terminate(1)
    Next
```

What I want to do is to close each of the instances of `app.exe` after different sleep times, any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use WScript.Shell's .Exec method to get a WshScriptExec objects for each session/run/instance of app.exe and .Terminate them at your leisure (and risk). See [Terminate Method (WshScriptExec)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/yk84ffsf%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)